# How to check if two XML elements in a WCF configuration file are functionally equivalent?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I want to write code to programmatically modify the WCF section of a .NET configuration file. Specifically, I want to be able to check for the existence of a particular kind of binding and add it if it is not present. However, checking for the existing binding turns out to be a little bit tricky.

To check if two bindings (or two configuration elements in general) are the same, here are the rules:

1. They must have the same element name (`<binding>` is not equivalent to `<behavior>`, for example)
2. They *may* have a different name attribute (e.g. `<binding name="MyBinding">` is equivalent to `<binding name="YourBinding">`, if everything else is the same)
3. All other attributes must have the same name and value, and every attribute in one element must exist in the other.
4. XML comments are ignored
5. All subelements must have their equivalent in the element under comparison, in both directions. So each subelement on the left side must have an equivalent on the right, and vice versa.
6. Subelements may appear in a different order. This has no effect on whether the two elements are equivalent.

I came up with the following code, which seems rather brute-force-ish:

```
static public bool IsEquivalentTo(this XElement source, XElement compareTo)
{
    if (source == null && compareTo == null) return true;
    if (source == null || compareTo == null) return false;
    if (source.Equals(compareTo)) return true;

    //Compare element name
    if (source.Name != compareTo.Name) return false;

    //Compare all attributes except the "Name" attribute (which is different from the element's name proper)
    var attributes = source.Attributes().ToDictionary( x => x.Name, x => x.Value);
    if (attributes.Count != compareTo.Attributes().Count()) return false;

    foreach (var a in attributes)
    {
        if (a.Key == "name") continue;
        if (a.Value != compareTo.Attribute(a.Key).Value) return false;
    }

    //Compare subelements. Each element on the left must have a matching element on the right. ,and vice versa. 
    var lhs = source.Elements().ToList();
    var rhs = compareTo.Elements().ToList();
    foreach (var l in lhs)
    {
        bool found = false;
        foreach (var r in rhs)
        {
            if (l.IsEquivalentTo(r))
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) return false;
    }
    foreach (var r in rhs)
    {
        bool found = false;
        foreach (var l in lhs)
        {
            if (r.IsEquivalentTo(l))
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is there a simpler way to accomplish this?

Here is a [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/klVKaF) with some test cases, if you'd like to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check equality for everything except name, then I suggest you can set the same name for both elements and use something like [XNode.DeepEquals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.deepequals.aspx)